# Can't send email via PHPMailer

Tags: linux, centos, php, iptables

I'm using the PHPMailer class to send email from an online application, it works fine on development server, and if I disable iptables. However whenever iptables is started, no mail sends - it seems to queue until I stop iptables - it then sends.

I originally followed instructions from here on iptables setup:

> https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-setup-a-basic-ip-tables-configuration-on-centos-6

Any advice is great appreciated!

Here's my iptables rules:

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
fail2ban-SSH  tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:22 
DROP       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp flags:0x3F/0x00 
DROP       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp flags:!0x17/0x02 state NEW 
DROP       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp flags:0x3F/0x3F 
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:80 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:443 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:25 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:465 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:22 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp spt:25 state ESTABLISHED 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:25 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:465 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW tcp dpt:587 

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp spt:25 state NEW,ESTABLISHED 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:25 state NEW,ESTABLISHED 

Chain fail2ban-SSH (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
REJECT     all  --  **IP ADDRESS OF SERVER***       0.0.0.0/0           reject-with icmp-port-unreachable 
RETURN     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```

Finally, PHPMailer doesn't give any error message, so I'd assume it successfully offloads it.

Here's a typical example of an email send script:

```
require_once(BASE_DIR.'classes/class.phpmailer.php');
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$body = 'html content';
$recipients = explode(',', $data['user_email'] );
foreach ($recipients as $recipient) {
    $mail->AddAddress(trim($recipient));
}
$mail->AddReplyTo( APP_EMAIL_SEND, APP_NAME);
$mail->IsHTML(TRUE);
$mail->From = APP_EMAIL_SEND;
$mail->FromName = APP_NAME;
$mail->Subject = 'Subject';
$mail->Body = $body;
$mail->Send();
```

Comment: That guide is so full of problems it would take me an hour just to explain them all. Just use a firewall configuration tool.

Comment: Hi @MichaelHampton - do you have any better resources/articles you can suggest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are blocking all UDP traffic on the server, so DNS lookups don't work either. You should allow traffic from/to UDP port 53.